# Conditional sentences to understanding practice

Tags: conditional-constructions

It's said that 2nd conditional are used to talk about unreal and impossible things but i think it is possible things.
Here are some examples of 2nd conditionals :

1.if people complained ,things would change.
(Does it mean I'm wishing people to complain in future to get the things changed ? )

2.if i didn't have headache, i would go to the party.

(Does it mean I'm wishing me to be healthy or i have headache now ?)

Things getting chanded and going to the party is possible if the required conditions are fullfilled. But why it's said to be impossible?

I'm confused in their meanings could you please make me clear ?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. If people complained, things would change.

---> People aren't complaining, so it's impossible for the things to change.

> 2. If I didn't have a headache, I would go to the party.

---> I have a headache now, so it's impossible for me to go to the party.

If the conditions do get fulfilled, it should be possible for these things to happen maybe in the future or some other time, but based on the situation ***at the moment***, they are impossible to happen or unreal. I found these two sites that explain about the second conditional:

http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/second-conditional.html   http://www.englishteachermelanie.com/grammar-the-2nd-second-conditional/

I hope you find them helpful:)

Comment: Do you mean 2nd conditional is used while talking about an event in present and we wish or imagin it would be different than present situation to happen something ? For example:
 
# suppose it's sunny day  and i image and say like this:
   >If it rained, i would get wet.

Comment: Yes! Or at least that's how I learned.

Comment: What if i say , if it rains if I'll wet. Can't. I say like this at that situation in sunny day ?

Comment: If + [sentence that describes what is not the reality], [result from that].  Therefore, the result will always not be something that's possible or real, right?

Comment: Yea, you can only use that ”If it rained/rains...” only when it's not raining.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I mean, can i say "If it rains ,I'll get wet" in the same situation in sunny day ?

Comment: I'm sorry! No, you can't use that sentence in the same situation. In the case of your example sentence, ”If it RAINS, I'll get wet.” is more likely to be used when rain can actually be expected (e.g., it's already cloudy and looks like it's going to rain) whereas ”If it RAINED, I'd get wet.” is more likely to be used when it's so sunny and you can't even imagine that it's going to start raining.

Comment: If it rained would probably be best used somewhere in like a desert where it hardly rains I think.

Comment: because rain is within the range that can be expected in most of the places we live.

Comment: I see what you mean , can we use 2nd conditional even in the situation when sth isn't very likely to happen but we believe it to happen?  In that example situation

Comment: Suppose:  i believe my friend who isn't hardworking student and i think he will pass his exam if he does hard work. Can i tell him ," if you study hard you'll  pass your exam"

Comment: Yea, if you really believe that he will study and pass that exam, you can tell him/her that. But then, if you know that he will not study, it'll be If you studied.

Comment: Oh i got it . In conclusion i would say "2nd conditional is all about imagination and supposition not about fact

Comment: YAY! you got it! :)